# Python to print remote SSH execution and output on Ubuntu from Windows cmd line

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, remote-access, paramiko

Using Python 3.x and the paramiko module I am looking to print out remote terminal text (stdout) from a Ubuntu machine.  I am sending commands from a Windows7 CMD window across the LAN to a Linux (Ubuntu) machine and printing the Linux output on my Windows CMD window.

So far I am ok using the code below to print out general commands like 'ifconfig' and 'ls', however the real command I want to send actually executes a program from Linux command line, with reference to two xml files.

here's the command I hope to run:

```
"./tool-to-run conf/first.xml second.xml"
```

Normally when I directly enter the command in Linux the terminal executes the successfully and the output would scroll across the Linux terminal for a few seconds (generally giving execution output).  But when I run my script below from my Windows CMD window, I just get a new windows prompt (after a second or so).  I am guessing the slight delay means the command is actually executing on the Linux PC in the background, but the output isn't returned to my Windows PC.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Here's the working code for the general 'ifconfig' and 'ls' commands

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
host = '11.22.33.44'
port, user, password = 22, 'me', 'mypass'
ssh.connect(host, port,  user, password)
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("./tool-to-run conf/first.xml second.xml")

for line in stdout.readlines():
    if line == "":
        pass
    else:
        print (line)

ssh.close()
```

Comment: The code that you posted doesn't check stderr. Is the process generating any output to stderr?

Comment: Hi Kenster, sorry should've checked stderr first.  The error I get is 

    "bash: ./tool/tool-to-run: No such file or directory"

Looks like a directory issue, I have my tool installed under 'opt' directory.  Forgive me I'm not too good at the Linux environment.  Guess I need to try and get the full directory tree to point to the application